# Why do they name the EventArgs parameter 'e'?

Tags: .net, variables, naming

As all of us know, .NET has very good documentation and variable/parameter naming. Oftentimes, you can figure out how to pass parameters to a function just by variable names shown at design time without consulting the documentation at all. Something that is very interesting for me is that the only variable that has an unrelated name is `e` which is used in nearly all event function declarations such as:

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
`private void button1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)`

My question is why do they name all event arguments `e`? Is there history behind it?

Comment: It's just a convention, and the e is always in the same place in the argument list, and it has the `EventArgs` type, so it's fairly obvious what it is after you see it for the first time.

Comment: It's actually not just common to .net. I think it predates that... a lot of event-driven frameworks use `e` to hold the event args.

Comment: so why they didnt name it lowercase event? or lowercase eventargs? why they use a single character variable name? using this single character variables are not appropriate due to readability issue!

Comment: Why do you call your loop variables `i` instead of `indexIntoArrayListOfPersonnelRecords`? Calling the variable `eventArgs` doesn't even add any information!

Comment: @HPT - `event` is a keyword; it would require `@event` - and besides; it **isn't** the event - it is the data *about* the event#

Comment: so why they dont call all streams s, all threads t, all processes p?

Comment: @HPT I disagree that it has readability issues. It's readable exactly because people tend not to use one-variable names - only the framework and just about only here. This variable name is special because of convention. It has almost become like a reserved word - if you're in "the context" of an event, you can expect the event args to be there and having the name e. This gives the programmer the opportunity to use some other variable names for e.g. a more strictly typed variable holding the same value.

Comment: @marc Gravell: I just wanted to make an example. you are write.

Comment: Because for stream, thread and process variables, the variable name can convey additional descriptive information. For the EventArgs parameter *there is no additional information*. The type of the parameter tells you everything you need to know about it.

Comment: @HPT - OK then... what would *you* call it, and what extra value would that name convey?

Comment: @marc: when you use a string and it means something as a variable in your code you just name it s? or look for a appropriate name for it?

Comment: HPT: You seem to be ignoring the questions that Marc is asking. Can you or can you not think of a better name for that parameter? Is any extra value your "better name" conveys worth more than the consistency gained by the `(sender, e)` signature common to *every* (user and library) event handler? Why does everything need a descriptive name? (Remember that over-describing things actually *reduces* clarity!)

Comment: @anon & Marc: at least the holder of that event could make sense, for example: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs button1_ClickArgs)

Comment: @HPT: What extra information does that convey? Is it worth the loss of consistency? When I see `(sender, e)` it's immediately apparent that it's an event handler. Inside an event handler, it's immediately apparent that `e.Foo` is accessing the EventData. Consistency and conventions are far more important than making names as descriptive as possible.

Comment: @HPT the delegate can't call it button1... As it knows nothing of such. Your handler can call it **anything it likes**. In your local handler, go to town; call it what you like - it'll work.

Comment: @Anon: so conventions tells us to use i as loop variable ? would you really do that always ?

Comment: @HPT: When the loop variable is being used solely as an index into an array, then yes! Overdescribing irrelevant aspects of the code makes the important details less clear. Are you really telling me you'd give loop variables 20-character names to describe exactly how they index into a particular collection?

Comment: @marc: assume you want to make a new instance of an eventargs in a eventhandler like button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) so because it is convention and your new eventargs doesn't convey any extra information you should name it 'e1' or 'ee'? what if you like to make so many EventArgs instances there? so appropriate names for them is mandatory isn't it?

Comment: @HPT: If you're creating new instances of EventArgs to invoke *other* events with, then yes you should give those descriptive names. You don't need to use the same names that the event itself does!

Comment: @Anon: no I wont, read the comment I just posted @marc. if you have so many loops inside each other would you use i, ii, i1, i2, i3, ... or you use for example imageindex, iconindex, fileindex, ... as variable names?

Comment: @HPT: If you're nesting loops to the degree that you need those descriptive variable names, then your code is poorly-written regardless of what you call your loop indices. At the very least, you should use `foreach` instead and then you don't need to call the index anything!

Comment: @HPT: If you're creating new EventArgs to invoke other events with, you should give them descriptive names. If you're not going to invoke other events with them, *then you shouldn't be creating new EventArgs*. It's like trying to pound in a nail with a shopping bag instead of going to get a hammer.

Comment: I think a better question is why didn't they just call "sender", "s"? ;)

Comment: Or even better, "why didn't they paint the bikeshed blue?" :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality

Comment: Perhaps amazingly enough, this is most likely a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193873/can-you-explain-the-reason-of-the-popularity-of-e-to-refer-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah! It was some lazy Microsoft Programmer :). Lolz jokes apart, this is an actual event naming guideline of Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s

This is what the third bullet says.

"Specify two parameters named sender and e. The sender parameter represents the object that raised the event. The sender parameter is always of type object, even if it is possible to use a more specific type. The state associated with the event is encapsulated in an instance of an event class named e. Use an appropriate and specific event class for the e parameter type."

Answer (score 2):

e is short for event, just like args is short for arguments, and i is short for index.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `e` is short for event.

Or as someone else once said.. `e` stands for extra stuff!

Answer (score 0):

It really should be given a more descriptive name, but its so widely used, accepted, and easily understood it has just stuck.

Comment: so use instead of integers i everywhere? It's not a reasonable answer

Answer (score 0):

e = event

It's unusual at first, but the human brain has a so good ability to adapt to almost anything, that I think it's not a real problem to call them e. Maybe evt or event are more descriptive, but you have to type more characters again and again.

For instance the Euler number is also called "e" instead of "Euler's number" to simplify things, spare a time waste of mathematicians' life. It's not too descriptive, but people got used to it without a problem and it's only one character, so I think e for event is fair enough.